# Excel Formula, Find Nearest Friday, Whatever is closer , Previous Friday or Next Friday

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ive tried many formulas trying to get this to work..

If this is in A1 `4/15/2024` would return `4/12/2024`.
but if the date is closer to the next friday , return that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test whether the date is Tuesday or not then either finds the next Friday or the subtracts a week and finds the next Friday:

```
=LET(dt,A1,wkd,WEEKDAY(dt),IF(wkd>=3,dt+6-MOD(wkd,7),dt-1-MOD(wkd,7)))
```

[image]

Comment: why tuesday? is that because that is the halfway point between the fridays and you can find which has more/less days to it?

Comment: Yes, you said you wanted to go up or down depending on which is closest.  I arbitrarily choose Tuesday as the cut point.  If you want Wednesday or Monday, change the `wkd>=3` to either `wkd>=4` or `wkd>=2` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the return type parameter in the `WEEKDAY()` formula basically performs a MOD on the Date, this formula can be used (assuming Tuesday is the midpoint):

`=B3+4-WEEKDAY(B3,12)`

the table below shows in column B-D individual components of the formula with column F the end result:

[image]

Comment: I figured there was a more streamline method.